# Optimizing complex list operation involving summation over multiple tuples (in python)

Tags: python, list

In a python app, users upload photos and are scored according to upvotes and unique comments. Now imagine we have a tuple for every photo, of the format: `(uploader_id, vote_score, comment_count)`. Next, imagine we maintain a list of tuples for all photos uploaded.

E.g. a sample list can be: `[(1,12,3),(1,-1,6),(2,30,10),(1,0,0),(2,0,1)]`. This shows 5 photos were uploaded, 3 by `uploader_id` 1, and 2 by `uploader_id` 2.

I want to reduce the aforementioned list to `[(uploader_id, net_score)]`. Here `net_score` is the aggregate of all `vote_score` and `comment_count` values for a particular user, divided by the number of photos uploaded by the said user.

E.g. the aforementioned sample list would yield `[(1,(11+9)/3),(2,(30+11)/2)]` = `[(1,6.67),(2,20.5)]`

What's the most performant way to do this list operation? I've accomplished it (see below) but with multiple for loops. Is there a more efficient way?

---

Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

photos_score_list = # list of the format [(uploader_id, vote_score, comment_count)]
photos_total_score_list= [ (k,v1+v2) for k,v1,v2 in photos_score_list]
total_photos = Counter(elem[0] for elem in photos_total_score_list) #dictionary, e.g. Counter({2: 8, 1: 7})
total_scores = defaultdict(int)
for key,val in photos_total_score_list:
    total_scores[key] += val
uploader_scores = []
for key,val in total_scores.items():
    uploader_scores.append(key)
    uploader_scores.append(val/total_photos[key])
set_benchmark(uploader_scores)
```

Note that `uploader_scores` ends up with unpacked tuples (i.e. `[1,6.67,2,20.5]` instead of `[(1,6.67),(2,20.5)]`. This is deliberate - I'm feeding the list to a redis-sorted set, and this is the best way to do it (i.e. don't worry about it).

Comment: Do you have any performance issue with your current code ? I would go against optimizing just for the sake of it

Comment: Yes I do. This is for a high traffic live app where performance has become critical. I wouldn't be asking this otherwise.

Comment: Hm, Why do you do not want to store already counted aggregate in DB or redis? In such scenario you will be updating it each time new photo is uploaded and have the data without any additional steps.

Comment: @SebastianOpałczyński: I'm creating the said list as an async task once every day - it's calculated for all photos uploaded in the past 24 hours. I use this list every time a new photo is uploaded: if the uploader's historical rank is above a certain percentile, their uploaded photo goes to more people's feeds. It's a way for me to reward people for photo quality, turning them into influencers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you get better performance using numpy / pandas. I would load the data in a DataFrame and use the grouping methods like this:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame

lst = [(1,12,3),(1,-1,6),(2,30,10),(1,0,0),(2,0,1)]
df = DataFrame(lst)
df[3] = df[1]+df[2] # adding the comment and vote count
```

The column with number `0` contains the uploader_id:

```
gb = df.groupby(0)
gb.agg(sum)
```

The last expression yields a DataFrame. The last Column contains the data you are interested in:

```
    1   2   3
0            
1   11  9   20
2   30  11  41
```

If you additionally would like to divide that by the number of photos uploaded by the user:

```
gb = df.groupby(0).aggregate(lambda x: np.sum(x)/float(len(x)))
```

which yields:

```
    1           2   3
0           
1   3.666667    3.0 6.666667
2   15.000000   5.5 20.500000
```

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve it using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) as:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_list = [(1,12,3),(1,-1,6),(2,30,10),(1,0,0),(2,0,1)]
vote_score_dict, comment_count_dict = defaultdict(int), defaultdict(int)

for uploader_id, vote_score, comment_count in my_list:
    vote_score_dict[uploader_id] += vote_score
    comment_count_dict[uploader_id] += comment_count

final_dict = {id: vote_score_dict[id]/float(comment_count_dict[id])  for id in vote_score_dict}
```

Final value hold be `final_dict` will be:

```
{1: 1.2222222222222223, 2: 2.727272727272727}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do without `photos_total_score_list`, it only keeps a sum of the `vote_score and comment_count`, do that when you're calculating the averages.

Your algorithm can be redone this way: loop over elements in `photos_score_list`, and keep a dictionary of key`id` and value `[scores, count]`, then divide in the end to get the averages. This way they only thing you're creating is the dictionary object in memory, and you loop over the data exactly once.

Answer (score 0):

Despite my comment, here my solution - reduced the number of fors from 4 to 2:

```
from collections import defaultdict, namedtuple

UserData = namedtuple('UserData', ['user_id', 'vote_score', 'comment_count'])

u_data = [
    UserData(1, 12, 3),
    UserData(1, -1, 6),
    UserData(2, 30, 10),
    UserData(1, 0, 0),
    UserData(2, 0, 1)
]

data = defaultdict(int)
count = defaultdict(int)

for s_data in u_data:
    data[s_data.user_id] += s_data.vote_score + s_data.comment_count
    count[s_data.user_id] += 1.0

output = [
    (user_id, score/count[user_id]) for user_id, score in data.iteritems()
]
```

Happy coding!